# How to update prices across all products from one place in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have more than 300 variations products. Now need to all the products pricing multiply it by 6. for Example if it is 10, then it should be 60...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To update the price of variation please use the `WP_Query` loop,

**Paste the below code in your current active theme functions.php file.**

```
$query = array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                'posts_per_page' => -1

            );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($query);

     //product loop 
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

       global $post;


            $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); // An instance of the WC_Product object

         // Only for variable products
         if( $product->is_type('variable') ){

            foreach( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation_values ){

              $variation_id = $variation_values['variation_id']; // variation id

              $regular_price  = get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', true);
              $regular_price  = $regular_price  * 6;

              // Updating active price and regular price
              update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $regular_price );
              update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $regular_price );

              wc_delete_product_transients( $variation_id ); // Clear/refresh the variation cache
           }
           // Clear/refresh the variable product cache
           wc_delete_product_transients( $post->ID );
         }
       }
       wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

I hope it helps you .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. but when I run the code, there is showing the below error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\woocommere\wp-content\themes\lookbook\functions.php:609 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdo..............

Comment: i have modified the answer please check again

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but still showing the error.